# How to align small square button right of textview?

Tags: android, android-layout

This may be dumb question but i couldn't find any solution for my problem, let me explain my problem am trying to align small square shaped button to right of text like in the below image i tried many things but nothing has helped me let me post what i have tried so far:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/content_spare_request"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/root1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/spare_text"
            android:layout_marginStart="2sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="07dp"
            android:text="@string/Spare"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/SForange"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_spare"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:background="@color/SForange"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spare_text"
            android:background="@color/SForange"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/spare_recyclerview"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="75dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:text="No Data Available"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use `drawableRight`

Comment: could you please elaborate @hrskrs then how to make that clickable

Comment: you want the plus button on the right side?

Comment: yaa like in the above image @AjayShrestha

Answer (score 0):

You can do below things.

1. Make width of relativelayout as match_parent.
2. Set btn_spare as right aligned and textview to start of btn_spare.

Comment: You need to put your textview and button in another relative layout. Do this it will work

Answer (score 0):

use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html). it gets you the ability to define exact location of view among others. for example you want a button under the imageview with specific distance between them, ConstraintLayout will give you something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `match_parent` for button height. Change your `Button` height from `match_parent` to specific height and add `android_background` to it:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_spare"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

tried this

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_spare_request"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/root1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="#fff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spare_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="07dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/tip_brush_size"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/facebook"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_spare"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/facebook"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spare_text"
        android:background="@color/facebook"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/spare_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="75dp"
        android:text="No Data Available"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change the color name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_spare_request"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/root1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="#fff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/spare_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Spare"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/SForange"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_spare"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/SForange"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:background="@color/SForange"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/spare_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="75dp"
        android:text="No Data Available"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```